# Jira: Link issue to external jira application

Tags: jira

I am using Jira and was wondering if anyone had any opinions or ideas on the best way to link two jira issues / projects together? From such a link I would hope to be able to add comment to a linked issue on application A and have the comment appear on application B.

I have been looking around and can see documentation about adding application links in order to allow communication between two applications.  I do not have rights on our Jira to test this out and I am unable to find documentation on what features you can gain from linking your application. If anyone has experience with this and could give me some information that be great!

Thank you

(I'm not sure if this is the right location to post this question, I wanted to put it on stackoverflow to try grab the larger number of users who would use Jira but it wouldn't let me post question as it had no code..)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue linking issues in different Jira projects, the link will show respectively on each issue if both projects are on the same Jira server. If the projects are on different servers you can add an [image: external link]:

There is no way that one comment added to an issue can show on another issue, however.

Answer (score -2):

There is a plugin that can do this job. please check 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.backbone.backbone-issue-sync/server/overview

..and they provide support too!